# Testing Normality

Tags: r, anova

I'm pretty new to stats, but I have about 78 data points which I'm testing for normality to determine whether I can use ANOVA on it. I did a qqnorm and qqline plot, but I'm unsure about whether the deviation from the qqline is enough to indicate that I cannot use ANOVA. How far from the line can my points deviate, and when is my data skewed enough that I cannot use ANOVA?

Here is my `Q-Q Plot`

[image]

Comment: This is a statistics question, that would be better asked on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). It is highly likely that a nearly identical question has been asked there already.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111010/interpreting-qqplot-is-there-any-rule-of-thumb-to-decide-for-non-normality ; but (1) see also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless ... Normality is the *least* important assumption underlying the validity of ANOVA, i.e. ANOVA is fairly robust to non-Normality; (2) you should be looking at the *residuals* of a linear model fit to your data, not the raw data themselves.  Can you post your data?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your help and the links you've provided. The plot I provided was the plot of residuals for linear fit, I forgot to mention that in my original posting. I'm not doing super sophisticated analysis, so if ANOVA is fairly robust to non-normality, then that should be good enough for my purposes since the shapiro test showed the data I have been qqplotting to be fairly close to be significance levels I was using!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shapiro-Wilks test for normality should suffice:

```
data = rnorm(1000,0,1)
shapiro.test(data)

#Output
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  data
W = 0.99886, p-value = 0.7952
```

CAUTION: The null hypothesis is that the data IS normally distributed. Hence the example above, since the data is indeed normally distributed.

Comment: So I just want to do shapiro.test(x), i don't want to run the test on the residuals?

Comment: Correct, for clarifcation of the assumptions necessary for a linear model check out http://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-linear-regression/